# EJB jndi address in wildfly

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, wildfly, wildfly-8

I had all my class files in WEB-INF folder of WAR file under classes which I removed and bundled into a jar file and loaded the jar as module

```
wildfly-home/modules/system/layers/base
```

I have some ejb's in that same code so while invoking the ejb
I modified the jndi address from

earlier it was

```
java:global/MyWarFileName/bean!interfacename  //this is working if classes are inside war file
```

to

```
java:global/MyJarName/bean!interfacename
```

As i guess the ModuleName is either war file name or jar name

But it cannot find the ejb.

Pls explain I an new to ejb.

**Update:**

Deployed the jar on server and added the module in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.MyJarName.jar" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This is working but Is there way to do the same through modules.i.e. jar file will loading from modules

Comment: Did you create jandex index for your jars that are in static modules? If not, server cannot find any annotations on your classes which explains why EJBs don't work.

Comment: @ctomc Pls share some tutorial links of  jandex index.

Comment: Why would you use a module as bean? Modules are made to satisfy dependencies, if you want to use a bean, why dont you just deploy it?